# GridLayout to fit full screen

Tags: android, xml

I want my Layout to like this:

[Layout Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoVOY.jpg)

Now I worked with GridLayout and this is my current XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:background="#000000"
 >


<GridLayout
android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnCount="2"
android:fillViewport="true"
>

<!-- Button 1 -->
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/B1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="@drawable/schalt2"
    />

<!-- Button 2 -->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/B2"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Button 2"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="@drawable/schalt2"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/B3"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 3"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="@drawable/schalt2"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/B4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_columnSpan="1"
    android:layout_rowSpan="2"

    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/schalt2"
    android:text="Button 4"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<!-- Button 5-->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/B5"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 5"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="@drawable/schalt2" />

<!-- Button 6 -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/B6"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/VIP"
    android:text="Button 6"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="@drawable/schalt2"
    />

</GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Well there is a lot of empty space left as you can see:
[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpRRv.jpg)

How can I get the GridLayout to match my parents height?

I tried it also with a Tab Layout but when reaching Button 2 and Button 3 with Button 4 to fit 2 rows than the TayLayout comes to it's limits.
What can I do now?

Comment: This is what you are looking for  https://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/

Comment: It seems a little bit tricky for my simple case. I need a OnClickListener to start Activities with these buttons and a certain design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Google `flexbox-layout` to achieve this. Here's the link: - [GoogleFlexboxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)

Add `dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.0'
}`

XML: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="4"
app:alignContent="stretch"
app:alignItems="stretch"
app:flexWrap="wrap">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/B1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:text="Button 1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:flexDirection="column"
    app:layout_flexBasisPercent="50%">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/B2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:text="Button 2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/B3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:text="Button 3"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        />

</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/B4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    android:text="Button 4"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_flexBasisPercent="50%" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/B5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
    android:text="Button 5"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/B6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:text="Button 6"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

 </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

Comment: Hello Sir. I got another Question to this Topic - maybe you as an experienced User can help me out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45175407/flexboxlayout-with-buttons-with-background-images-how-to-maintain-their-size