# FlexboxLayout with Buttons with Background Images, how to maintain their size

Tags: android, android-layout, button, background

this is my XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/main_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:alignContent="stretch"
    app:alignItems="stretch"
    app:flexWrap="wrap"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    >


<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:flexDirection="column"

    >

    <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:flexDirection="row"
        app:layout_flexBasisPercent="25%"
        >
    <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:flexDirection="column"
        app:layout_flexBasisPercent="50%"

        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/istilldontknow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:text="istilldontknow"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/istilldontknow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:text="@string/istilldontknow"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />
    </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>



     <Button
        android:id="@+id/istilldontknow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:text="@string/istilldontknow"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_flexBasisPercent="50%"
         />

    </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_flexGrow="1"
    >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/events"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:text="@string/Event"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_weight="4"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/checkin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:text="@string/checkin"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_weight="4"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/podcast"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:text="Play some Music"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_weight="2"

        />



</LinearLayout>

</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>

</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

As you can see I got a Background Image which is taken from the Internet, nothing special at this point

Good, now I want to make my Homescreen look like this with the given heights and widths I have defined in the color scheme in the xml above:
[Main Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11qqF.jpg)

As you can see in the PS File, there is a TextLayer with the Text Design, and a Layer which contains the Background of the Button with a complex Background (pay attention to "Play some music" with the Wave-Form in the Background plus the individual elements on the button itself).

So far so good, I tried the easiest way first, export the image to -png, put it in my Drawables and then set my "android:background=" to the button. This is the result:
[Button with Background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqqK3.png)

As you can see here, the image doesn't fit the way I want it and also the text gets a bad scale.

So I tried to create .9.png file which contains the Text and the Background Layer but the scaling looks awful because I only can stretch my Image in certain areas not containing any text or pattern.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` of the required Button with `android:layout_height="0dp"` and it'll result something like this.

Image:
 [image]

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:alignContent="stretch"
app:alignItems="stretch"
app:flexWrap="wrap">


<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:flexDirection="column">

    <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:alignItems="stretch"
        app:flexDirection="row"
        app:layout_flexBasisPercent="25%">

        <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:flexDirection="column"
            app:flexWrap="nowrap"
            app:layout_flexBasisPercent="50%">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/istilldontknow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                android:text="i still dont know"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/istilldontknow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:text="i still dont know"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/istilldontknow11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:text="i still dont know"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_flexBasisPercent="50%" />

    </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10"
        app:layout_flexGrow="1">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/events"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="@drawable/nav_bg"
            android:text="EVENT"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/checkin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="@drawable/nav_bg"
            android:text="CHECK IN"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/podcast"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@drawable/nav_bg"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:text="Play some Music"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"

            />


    </LinearLayout>

</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>

</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```